# How can I efficiently pull specific information from JSON

Tags: ruby, json, calendar, google-calendar-api

I currently have a public Google calendar that I am successfully pulling JSON data down using [Google's API](http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/colorado.edu_mdpltf14q21hhg50qb3e139fjg@group.calendar.google.com/public/full?alt=json&orderby=starttime&max-results=15&singleevents=true&sortorder=ascending&futureevents=true).

I am using HTTParty to convert the JSON to a ruby object.

```
response = HTTParty.get('http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/colorado.edu_mdpltf14q21hhg50qb3e139fjg@group.calendar.google.com/public/full?alt=json&orderby=starttime&max-results=15&singleevents=true&sortorder=ascending&futureevents=true')
```

I want to retrieve many titles, event names, start times, end times ect.  I can get these with commands like

```
response["feed"]["title"["$t"]
```

for the calendar's title, and

```
response["feed"]["entry"][0]["title"]["$t"]
```

for the event's title.

My question is two-fold.  One, Is there a simpler way to pull this data? Two, how can I go about pulling multiple events information?  I tried:

```
response.each do |x| response["feed"]["title"]["$t"]
```

but that spits out a no implicit conversion of string into integer error.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your examples this should do it

```
 response["feed"]["entry"].map {|entry| entry["title"]["$t"] }
```

Answer (score 0):

`response['feed']['entry']` is a simple array of hashes. It is probably best to extract that array to a temporary variable with

```
entries = response['feed']['entry']
```

thereafter your code it depends entirely on what you need to achieve. For instance, using the URL that you have provided

```
puts entries.length
```

shows

```
2
```

And

```
entries.each do |entry|
  puts entry['title']['$t']
end
```

gives

```
NEW EVENT
Future EVENT
```

If we can help you to achieve something specific then please alter your answer or ask for clarification in a comment.

Comment: specifically I want to create an array of arrays.  Each array should have all the data relating to each event. so Array[0][0] would be maybe the title from the first event, and Array[1][0] would be the title of the second event ect. I want title, event name, start time, end time, location, and description.